# How do I draw a transparent Rect in Android on my Custom View (extends View)?

Tags: android, pixel, transparent

How do I draw a Rect that basically creates a hole in the canvas? For example, say I have an image editing application that's made for Pixel art. The user touches an area of the screen, and draws a purple rectangle. Oops, he put the rectangle in the wrong spot. The user needs to make this purple square turn transparent again so that he can re-draw it in the right position.

How do I do this? I've used PorterDuff.Mode.Clear, myPaintColor.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT) etc. but all give the same result. An ugly black square where it should be transparent. My canvas starts out as transparent, and can be saved via getDrawingCache to a transparent .PNG, so I know the canvas starts off as transparent. But how do I help my user who drew the purple square to make his canvas transparent again? Thanks. I've been trying to figure this out all day, reading all the documentation on this, but I can't figure it out.

Here's what I have:

```
            Rect square = new Rect();
            Paint drawColor = new Paint();
            //drawColor.setColor(UserColor.get(i));
            drawColor.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.CLEAR));
            square.set(CanvasFractionWidth * UserX.get(i), CanvasFractionHeight * UserY.get(i), (CanvasFractionWidth * UserX.get(i)) + (CanvasFractionWidth), (CanvasFractionHeight * UserY.get(i)) + CanvasFractionHeight);
            canvas.drawRect(square, drawColor);
```

Comment: Mmhh, if you have a custom view, then just don't draw anything in your onDraw method...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [RoboDemo](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/RoboDemo), I use this :

```
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setXfermode( new PorterDuffXfermode( Mode.CLEAR ) );
```

Comment: So maybe you got the wrong approach. Users can draw primitives or free forms ?

Comment: Primitives, as in squares set to a size? Yes.

Comment: Ok, so you should try a different approach : store all the primitives drawn on screen by using their coordinates and sizes and colors, then redraw them each time your screen is drawn and take care of erasing everything else before. That's a much more robust approach TMHK.

Comment: Yeah, I was kind of thinking that might work. I just thought that there might be an easier method of doing it.

Comment: Actually having full control over your model is quite interesting from a software design point of view, I am pretty sure it will allow you to go further in your app that what you can expect right now.